# Phonegap - Javascript, making a variable out of a object

Tags: javascript, variables, object, cordova

Using Phonegap with its SQL function, I get my query returns in the form of

```
results.rows.item(i).Title
```

where results.rows.item(i) is per object and the .Title will specify which field to select.

This is only one of several fields, so instead of writing it out a massive line several times, I wanted to declare it as a variable.

```
var details = "results.rows.item(i).Title + \' \' " +
        "+ results.rows.item(i).Street + ' ' " +
        "+ results.rows.item(i).PostalCode + ' ' " +
        "+ results.rows.item(i).Contact + ' ' " +
        "+ results.rows.item(i).ContactEmail + ' ' " +
        "+ results.rows.item(i).ContactPhone + ' ' " +
        "+ results.rows.item(i).OperatingHours + ' ' " +
        "+ results.rows.item(i).Operator + '</p></div>'"
```

Of course the resulting problem is, its a string when I try to use in the following line

```
$("#locations").append('<div data-role="collapsible"><h3>' + results.rows.item(i).Title + '</h3><p>' + details);
```

What can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm undestanding your question correctly, then you can use strings as property names by using bracketed notation rather than dot notation:

```
var details = [];
var item = results.rows.item(i);
["Title", "Street", "PostalCode", "Contact", "ContactEmail", "ContactPhone", "OperatingHours", "Operator"].forEach(function(field) {
    details[details.length] = item[field];
});
details = details.join(' ');
```

(Note that that uses ES5's [`forEach`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.18). If you may not be running in an ES5-enabled environment, you can use a shim [or rewrite the above to use a `for` loop].)

Basically, in JavaScript, you have two options for accessing the property of an object: You can use a literal property name with a dot, e.g. `foo.bar`; or you can use bracketed notation with a string, e.g. `foo["bar"]`. In the latter case, the string doesn't have to be a string literal, it can be the result of any expression. So all of these output the `bar` property of `foo`:

```
var foo = {bar: "baz"};
console.log(foo.bar);        // "baz"
console.log(foo["bar"]);     // "baz"
var s = "bar";
console.log(foo[s]);         // "baz"
var b = "b", a = "a", r = "r";
console.log(foo[b + a + r]); // "baz"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will append values for all fields in the current row

```
var rowData = results.rows.item(i);
var fieldName,fieldValue;

for(var fieldName in rowData) {
    fieldValue = rowData[fieldName];

    $("#locations").append('<div data-role="collapsible"><h3>' + fieldValue + '</h3><p>' + details);

}
```